# Table rows selection is cleared on table page change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a table where I can select rows with a checkbox, and each selected row is saved in a state with a list of ids.

Every time I change the table page, a request is made that overwrites the list displayed in the table, which makes the list of selected rows disappears.

When I select a new row on the new page, and when I return to the page where I had the checkboxes selected, it is no longer there.

My row function:

```
const rowSelection: any = {
    selectedRowKeys: listRowKeys,
    onChange: (selectedRowKeys, selectedRow) => {
      setListRowKeys(selectedRowKeys);
    },
  };
```

When I select:
[image]

Console print array:
[image]

I select a new row in the new page:
[image]

List overwritten:
[image]

I try to update the function by creating a new state and updating the new one with the old one, but it does not work.

```
const [selectedCloneList, setSelectedCloneList] = useState([]);
```

```
const rowSelection: any = {
    selectedRowKeys: listRowKeys,
    onChange: (selectedRowKeys, selectedRow) => {
      setListRowKeys([...selectedRowKeys, selectedCloneList]);
      setSelectedCloneList([...selectedRowKeys])
    },
  };
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is your components tree structure? In particular, where is your state defined, compared to your table pagination logic? Please make sure to share a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide codesandbox link